# Laravel Mail Service

Tags: laravel, email

Sorry i'm newbie, i'm using laravel 5.1 project and i want to use an email service to send an email.

I used mandrill before but it's paid mail service now that connect with mailchimp,

so i search another solution is mailgun, when i create mailgun account, it's need to be activated and i can't send email with it.

I set up gmail smtp at my local project and it's success send email, but when i push the setting to my server it show this error:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]
```

I confuse which email service must i use that easy to set up and easy to use?

Comment: please have a look at `http://www.mailgun.com/`. Its way easier to use

Comment: **sendgrid** mail service is easy . I have tried it. you can refer my repo :  https://github.com/YasinPatel/send-email-in-laravel-using-sendgrid

Answer (score 0):

the file mail.php has, for security reasons, the key values in the form of env variables that you must set in a separate file called .env (I include a sample further down below) and of course, you can use any free mail provider you have an account in, like gmail, hotmail, yandex etc.

first this is the mail.php file at config

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', $_ENV['MAIL_DRIVER']),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', $_ENV['MAIL_HOST']),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT',$_ENV['MAIL_PORT']),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => ['address' => 'beauty@beauty.com', 'name' => 'My App'],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', $_ENV['MAIL_USERNAME']),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', $_ENV['MAIL_PASSWORD']),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

];

Here is the .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
MAIL_PORT='465'
MAIL_USERNAME='beauty@beauty.com'
MAIL_PASSWORD='yourpassword'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Then in your controller you need to write the mail code, like this . I have include a picture where, as you can see, the names are taken from variables sent from a Form but you can replace them for testing purposes by hardcoded strings.

[image]

The last thing you need is the View that is actually sent to the email of the recipient, which, in this case we have called, "mailers" and can look like this:

[image]